# partitioning and serialization overhead in hazelcast

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have an IMap map where the Abc class is a nested class which implements serialization. Even with no sync and async backups I get an out of memory exception. When I reduce the no of partitions to 3 from the default 271 it seems to work and all entries get loaded successfully. What is the partitioning and serialization overhead incurred during MapLoading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reduce partition count to 3, you are slowing down the system by reducing the concurrency. There are multiple partition threads on each member in a cluster and each partition thread owns certain number of partitions. Reducing it to such low count would drastically impact the performance. Moreover, you can not have more than 3 members in the cluster (I think it may actually be 2) with 3 cluster wide partitions.

You were able to avoid OOME because there were less partition objects but it wont last long. You need to appropriately tune JVM heap size for required cache usage.

On Serialization overhead, Java serialization is the worst in terms of payload size and latency. Use Hazelcast serialization, here is the link: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#serialization

Comment: how can i find the total data size being loaded and the data residing per partition and the jvm heap size. Even when I increase the JVM heap size to -Xmx2048 using VM arguments I still run out of memory with 271 partitions. Earlier the application was using a static hashmaps and loading all the maps in the beginning and it was running fine now with just replacing one map with an IMap I get an out of memory error.

Comment: Can it be attributed to only partitioning and serialization or is it something else. I took out the heap dump and analysed it with Eclipse Memory Analyzer and it shows that the maploading implementation with 271 objects is the main culprit

Comment: What makes you believe that partition count is causing memory issues? How much data are you storing - entry count and size of each entry? Also, where are you seeing memory errors - on server or client or is it an embedded mode cluster? You can use Management Center to investigate data distribution and memory consumption.

Comment: I am seeing oome on the server size. I am testing a client-server topology on my local machine. The server runs as local application and the client runs on tomcat server on local as well

Comment: The number of entries are 2851

Comment: and the size of the mongodb collection is 24 MB

Comment: What is the size of each entry - is it 24 mb you said? What does Management Center show?

Comment: upon putting a print statement inside the loadAll method in my mapstore implementation I find that the loadAll method gets called 271 times and loads all the data each of those 271 times. What could be causing this.

Comment: found the error i was loading all the data all 271 times in loadAll method and not using the collection keys parameter being passed to the loadAll method

Comment: Cool. You can find more here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#initializing-map-on-startup